# Как распарсить строку 192.168.0.1/16

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Как распарсить строку 192.168.0.1/16

Comment: Опишите, что возможно получить на вход.

Если это IP-адрес, вам придётся рассматривать [много](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations) [разных](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_representation) форматов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри PHP это выполняется функцией

```
preg_match('|^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\/(\d{1,2})$|', '192.168.0.1/16', $matches);
```

функция возвращает true при успешном парсинге и false при неудаче.

в массиве $matches в результате успешного выполнения должен быть массив из 3 значений. В 0 вся строка которая соответствует регулярке. в 1 IP, во 2-м маска.

А можно проще без проверок лишних.

```
list( $ip, $mask ) = explode('/','192.168.0.1/16');
```